# VBA Chart to Image Copy/Paste Currency

Tags: excel, charts, vba

Used the site a lot for VBA problem solving and haven't had to ask a question yet - hoping someone can help.

I use this code to copy Excel sheet charts to another workbook as an image. The problem is where my chart has a measurement of currency and shows '£' in the Y axis, the chart image which pastes to the other workbook is always in dollars '$'.

Is there any way to force my charts to copy over with the GBP currency?

My code:

```
Windows(dsllng).Activate
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 8").CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
Windows(TdysFle).Activate
Range("B11").Select
Sheets("Ad-Selling Report Summary").Paste
```

thanks,

Ashley

Comment: I just created a sample data and it works just fine for me. Any chance I can have a peek at your workbook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to avoid that excel uses some kind of automatic setting of local formats for the ticklabel numberformat.

This code sets the ticklabel numberformat to GBP before copying the chart and sets it back to link to the cell data after copying.

```
Windows(dsllng).Activate
With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 8")
  .Chart.Axes(xlValue).TickLabels.NumberFormatLinked = False
  .Chart.Axes(xlValue).TickLabels.NumberFormat = "#,##0.00 £"
  .CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
  .Chart.Axes(xlValue).TickLabels.NumberFormatLinked = True
End With
Windows(TdysFle).Activate
Range("B11").Select
Sheets("Ad-Selling Report Summary").Paste
```

Should solve your problem

Comment: Many thanks Axel - this is perfect. I just needed to change from "#,##0.00 £" to "£#,##0.00" to fit with the rest of my charts. thanks!